# Why is my class not CLS-compliant?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, cls-compliant

This really baffles me. I've tried removing the readonly, changing names.. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public abstract class CatalogBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly String DataPath;
    protected readonly XmlSerializer Serializer;
    private readonly XmlSerializerNamespaces _namespaces;

    protected CatalogBase(String dataPath)
    {
        DataPath = dataPath;
        Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        _namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        _namespaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
    }

    public virtual void Write(T obj)
    {
        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(DataPath);

        Serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj, _namespaces);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    public abstract IDictionary<String, T> Read();
}
```

Edit:

The warning:

> *Warning  1   'Ar.ViewModel.Workspaces.MaterialCatalogBase': base type
>   'Or.Files.CatalogBase' is not
>   CLS-compliant C:_Center_Work_Programming_Cs\Ar\Ar\ViewModel\Workspaces\MaterialCatalogBase.cs 9   18  Ar*

## Edit2:

Even if I change the class as below I still get the error:

```
public abstract class CatalogBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly String DataPath;
    protected readonly XmlSerializer Serializer;
    private readonly XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces;

    protected CatalogBase(String dataPath)
    {
        DataPath = dataPath;
        Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
    }

    public virtual void Write(T obj)
    {
        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(DataPath);

        Serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj, namespaces);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    public abstract IDictionary<String, T> Read();
}
```

Also, I've forgotten to mention that I get two (exactly the same errors) for some reason.. ?

Comment: What is the exact warning message you're receiving?

Comment: We're not compilers, so please show where you get the non-CLS-compilance warning.

Comment: I don't actually get a warning when I compile this, everything looks fine.

Comment: Same here - no warnings (.Net4 on VS2012)

Comment: @DanielImms - See the example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8ak87y5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: It says private is okay for the leading underscore.

Comment: The CLS compliance police will come after you.

Comment: I wish it did, maybe it could coherently tell me what is wrong instead of giving me a cryptic warning msg.

Comment: Are your classes, `MaterialCatalogBase` and `CatalogBase`, in different assemblies?

Comment: They are, actually. MaterialCatalogBase is in a WPF Application project and CatalogBase is in a Class Library. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Pavel: Then perhaps the other assembly isn't marked as CLS Compliant? (or the class in it isn't).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have the following:

- Assembly A declares `CatalogBase<T>`. Assembly A **is not** marked as CLSCompliant
- Assembly B references assembly A. Assembly B declares `MaterialCatalogBase : CatalogBase<T>`. Assembly B **is** marked as CLSCompliant

If it is your case - then assembly in which your `CatalogBase<T>` class located should be marked with CLSCompliant attribute:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

Comment: Thank you.  The assembly containing my container class wasn't marked, but the consuming assemblies are.  Why the previous devs felt the need to ensure that this fully-contained webapp had to be CLS-compliant, IDK, but there we are.

Comment: @ScottPeterson, if there is no need anymore for it to be CLS-compliant, you can also end the compliance.